# Filtering a Database Query

Tags: php, database, options

In a [WP_List_Table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) example I'm using, I am seeing how to make a general query to the `wp_options` table in the Wordpress database.

For example, `$query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->options";`

I also see that we typically create a `foreach` loop to display all the records in this table on separate rows. Sounds easy enough.

But I would like to filter this query to reference an "options array" instead.  This is a single value in my table.  For example, I want to query a single option called `testimonial_settings` and then retrieve all the array values from this single field. I can't wrap my head around how I would do this using a `foreach` loop.

Maybe a simple example showing the proper syntax would help clear things up....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table `wp_options` can normally be queried using [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)

So you can use something like

```
$testimonial_settings = get_option('testimonial_settings');
```

to retrieve the values of `testimonial_settings`. If the stored value is serialized, it will be retrieved as an array.

Comment: So WP_List_Table does not care "how" we access the options, right? That's great!  None of the WP_List_Table examples out there are using `get_option('blah')` to access settings.  I have only seen database query methods.

Comment: It just depends what you want to do. If you're having a plugin having lots of settings, it is recommended to use a single entry in the `wp_options` table and store your data as an array. Storing each settings in its own field can result in more queries to fetch your data. It gets worse if `autoload` is set to true.